# Google Charts double hAxis Label?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I'm currently using Google Charts to produce some graphs, and I've come up against this problem.

I want to have two labels on my hAxis, and I cannot see any obvious solution on the developers site.

The image included gives an example of the kind of result I'm looking for, any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40240392/5090771)...