# Hierarchies graphs in google charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

How can I build something like this (with subcategories on the one of the axis)  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

although the requested layout is not available via standard configuration options,
it is possible to achieve, if you're ok with modifying the svg manually

when the chart's `'ready'` event fires, add the category labels and group lines

see following working snippet, which is just an example to show the possibility

several assumptions are made based on the size and placement of the chart...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['State', 'Store', 'Sales'],
    ['California', 'Donald\'s Market', 1560],
    ['California', 'Alexei\'s Specialties', 1090],
    ['California', '24-Seven', 345],
    ['Texas', 'Albert Market', 245],
    ['Texas', 'Jim\'s Market', 245],
    ['Texas', 'International Food Store', 82]
  ]);

  var options = {
    bars: 'horizontal',
    chartArea: {
      left: 204
    },
    height: 400,
    vAxis: {
      textStyle: {
        fontSize: 10
      }
    }
  };

  var chartDiv = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(chartDiv);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([1, 2, {
    calc: 'stringify',
    sourceColumn: 2,
    type: 'string',
    role: 'annotation'
  }]);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var rowIndex = -1;
    var stateValue = '';
    var svgParent = chartDiv.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(chartDiv.getElementsByTagName('text'), function(text) {
      var groupLabel;
      if ((text.getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'end') &&
          (parseFloat(text.getAttribute('x')) < 200)) {
        rowIndex++;
        if (stateValue !== data.getValue(rowIndex, 0)) {
          stateValue = data.getValue(rowIndex, 0);
          groupLabel = text.cloneNode(true);
          groupLabel.setAttribute('x', '60');
          groupLabel.innerHTML = stateValue;
          svgParent.appendChild(groupLabel);
          addGroupLine(groupLabel, -24);
        }
        if (rowIndex === (data.getNumberOfRows() - 1)) {
          addGroupLine(text, 16);
        }
      }
    });

    function addGroupLine(text, yOffset) {
      var groupLine = chartDiv.getElementsByTagName('rect')[0].cloneNode(true);
      groupLine.setAttribute('y', parseFloat(text.getAttribute('y')) + yOffset);
      groupLine.setAttribute('x', '16');
      groupLine.setAttribute('height', '0.8');
      groupLine.setAttribute('width', '188');
      groupLine.setAttribute('stroke', 'none');
      groupLine.setAttribute('stroke-width', '0');
      groupLine.setAttribute('fill', '#000000');
      svgParent.appendChild(groupLine);
    }
  });

  chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Hi,I'm trying to do something like this.Can you explain more about rowIndex? if I have view.setColumns([{type:'string',calc:function (dt, row) {return dt.getFormattedValue(row, 5)}},9,10,11])-- and I want to add column 6 to display as subcategories,How should I set rowIndex? or what should the code be? (I'm getting data from google sheet)