# Google Chart, Can we control the annotation parameter for individual points in the chart

Tags: charts, annotations, google-visualization

I want to draw a box using annotations. Though annotation provides 
parameters to draw box at every point in the chart.

But using this it will draw a box to every point in the chart see the google [docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart).

In the given docs, it draws box at both the points. Is it possible to draw the box only at one point.

See `JSFiddle`, at top of each vertical line box is written, I want to draw this inside a box or rectangle.

See below image to understand my requirement:

[image]

Comment: to draw the box, you could simply add your own _svg_ to the chart, once the `'ready'` event fires. add a `rect` element, and `text` elements for content. for placement, check methods for `chart.getChartLayoutInterface().getXLocation` & `getYLocation` -- these methods will give you the chart coordinates for a specific x or y value -- [here is an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39553121/5090771) with example of these methods -- [here is an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40240392/5090771) with example of adding _svg_ elements to the chart